# `svn status` shows me a file as `!` and as `?`, why?

Tags: svn, file, conflict, status

If I do `svn status` in my working directory I get

```
?       skripte/data/somefile.csv
!       skripte/data/somefile.csv
```

`svn ? status` tells me

- '!' item is missing (removed by non-svn command) or incomplete
- '?' item is not under version control

How can a file be *not under version control* **AND** *svn complains about it as missing*?

Comment: svn update tells me `At revision 1199`. Nothing else.

Comment: Is this the actual output? Could there be a case mismatch? e.g. somefile.csv != someFile.CSV

Comment: Yes, this can be especially challenging when you create working copies on different operating systems where one filesystem is case-sensitive and the other not!

Comment: @Piskvor: the filenames are exactly the same. @ZoolWay: Regarding your comment I should perhaps add the information, that `somefile` has blanks in it and a character `ö` but they are identical. At least they are shown identical. I can't think why there should be a duplicate. Is there a way to remove *both*?

Comment: @Aufwind. Try `svn revert sripte/data/somefile.csv`

Comment: @Raghuram: `svn revert` produces `Skipped 'skripte/data/somefile.csv'`. :-/

Comment: @Aufwind. How about deleting the file locally (or moving it elsewhere in case you need it) and then doing `svn revert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

1. moving file `skripte/data/somefile.csv` to another place
2. `svn delete skripte/data/somefile.csv`
3. `svn commit -m=""`

   - `-m=""` means only, that I don't want to send a commit message here.

After those 3 steps `svn status` shows everything is correct.

Thanks to @ZoolWay, @Piskvor and @Raghuram for leading me towards the right direction and pointing out things, that helped me identify the error in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with some UTF-8 symbols (such as ü).

Here is a description of the problem with SVN.

http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-04/0841.shtml